# Services, android application and Leaflet map

Tags: services, javascript

I have a tricky question. I have a content type with a map where the user can provide a location by putting a marker on a leaflet map.
I am building an android app through witch the user will also be able to add new content, but I am stuck. I cannot find the right format of the location on the map to be sent. I use Services and build a json file. I have tried WKT and Geojson for latitude and longitude to be sent but without any luck. Does anyone know which format has to be used when the input for the site is a leaflet map??

Comment: Anyone who has an idea on how to omit the empty leaflet map please?